Paypal SFTP/API
I'm working on a project where we need to transition from using PayPal's SFTP service to their API for retrieving dispute data. Previously, we received a transformed report from the SFTP server in CSV format, with filenames like:
DisputeC_##############_##############D##-product_name.CSV
The CSV file contains the following columns: buyer_comments, buyer_email_address, buyer_first_name, buyer_last_name, case_filing_date, case_id, case_reason, case_status, case_type, chargeback_reason_code, disputed_amount, disputed_currency, disputed_transaction_id, final_outcome_reason, invoice_id, money_movement, response_due_date, seller_protection, seller_protection_currency, seller_protection_payout_amount, settlement_type, transaction_id, transaction_initiation_date, outcome
Now, I need to replicate this report using the PayPal API. The challenges I’m facing are:

Mapping API Data to CSV Columns: How can I identify the specific tables and fields in the API that correspond to these CSV columns?
Understanding Transformations: How can I know what transformations PayPal applied to the data in the SFTP report so that I can apply the same logic in our API-based report?

I tried to use disputes, diputes_info and transactions tables, but i still see that in sftp report some columns have more types and etc

Why are you transitioning? The SFTP service is designed for this type of reporting.

I understand the SFTP service is tailored for this type of reporting, but our management has specifically requested this transition. My main concern is whether it’s possible to have an identical view through the API as we currently have with the SFTP service.
